# FusedLocationProviderClient, This method should only be accessed from tests or within package private scope

Tags: android-studio

I have a class in my project

```
public class LocateMe {
  public void locateMe(Activity activity) {
    mLocationClient = new FusedLocationProviderClient(activity);
.....
```

that uses FusedLocationProviderClient but I keep getting the warning "This method should only be accessed from tests or within package private scope" about the line new FusedLocationProviderClient(activity). I tried to tweak and change things without success.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following way to initialize it instead:

```
mLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getApplicationContext());
```

or use whatever context you got.